# Check if contract exists in list

Tags: solidity, contract-development, require

I've got a contract which creates another contracts and stores them in a list. How can I check that contract with specific index already exists?

```
import "./User.sol";

contract Main is Ownable {

    User[] private _users;

    function createUser(uint256 _id) onlyOwner external {
        // How can I check if User in list of _users??
        // I tried different approaches but it gives compilation or VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode errors

        // require(address(_users[_id]) == address(0), "User already exists.");
        User user = new User(_id);

        emit UserCreated(user, _users.length);

        _users.push(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unsure of what you want, but assuming `_id` is unrelated to an item's position in the list and you require a way to enumerate the `User`s in the system, you probably need both an array and a mapping, i.e.:

```
import "./User.sol";

contract Main is Ownable {

    User[] private _users;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) userExists;

    function createUser(uint256 _id) onlyOwner external {
        require(!userExists[_id], "User already exists.");
        userExists[_id] = true;

        User user = new User(_id);

        emit UserCreated(user, _users.length);

        _users.push(user);
    }
}
```

If you don't need to enumerate the `User`s, then just a mapping (`mapping(uint256 => User)`) will do, as in @goodvibration's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mapping instead of an array:

```
mapping (uint256 => User) private users;
uint256 private numOfUsers;

function createUser(uint256 _id) onlyOwner external {
    require(users[_id] == User(0), "User already exists");
    users[_id] = new User(_id);
    emit UserCreated(users[_id], ++numOfUsers);
}
```